# Ubuntu 16.10 Desktop (32-bit) file please

Tags: 32-bit, 16.10

I want download the Ubuntu 16.10 Desktop (32-bit) › but the systemonly lets me get the 64-bit

Comment: the  alternate download only has it through bit-torrent

Answer (score 3):

You can find the torrent file for the 32-bit version about the middle of the page of the following link:

https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

or the ISO from here:

http://releases.ubuntu.com/yakkety/

Hope this helps!

Comment: it only has link to bit-torrent

Comment: @Saswat Sorry about that.  Updated to a secondary link you can find the 32-bit at.

Comment: http://releases.ubuntu.com/yakkety/ubuntu-16.10-desktop-i386.iso

Should work !!

Comment: @Saswat Yes, I updated my answer to take you to that page.

Comment: oh shap didn't see it . thank you for the link greatly appreciated